# How to show reflection of coverflow widget in android?

Tags: android

hi in my project i've coverflow widget.  i'm using  code for that coverflow  widget is  in this link
[this is the link i'm using](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2012/12/17/coverflow-android-complete-implementation-source-code/)
i want to implement reflection for that whole widget

thanks in advance

hi i'm using this method but not getting reflection,is any thing wrong in this? for coverflow widget

```
public boolean createReflectedImages() {
        // The gap we want between the reflection and the original image
        System.out.println(" i'm from createReflected image()");
        final int reflectionGap = 4;//4

        int index = 0;
        for (int imageId : mImageIds) 
        {
            Bitmap originalImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                    getResources(), imageId);
            int width = originalImage.getWidth();
            int height = originalImage.getHeight();
            //int width=100;
            //int height=100;

            // This will not scale but will flip on the Y axis
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

            //matrix.preScale(-1.0f, 1.0f); 
            //Bitmap mirroredBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(originalImage, 0, 0, originalImage.getWidth(), originalImage.getHeight(), matrix, false);

            matrix.preScale(1, -1);

            // Create a Bitmap with the flip matrix applied to it.
            // We only want the bottom half of the image
            Bitmap reflectionImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(originalImage, 0,
                    height / 2, width, height / 2, matrix, false);

            // Create a new bitmap with same width but taller to fit
            // reflection
            Bitmap bitmapWithReflection = Bitmap.createBitmap(width,
                    (height + height / 2), Config.ARGB_8888);

            // Create a new Canvas with the bitmap that's big enough for
            // the image plus gap plus reflection
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmapWithReflection);
            // Draw in the original image
            canvas.drawBitmap(originalImage, 0, 0, null);
            // Draw in the gap
            Paint deafaultPaint = new Paint();
            canvas.drawRect(0, height, width, height + reflectionGap,
                    deafaultPaint);
            // Draw in the reflection
            canvas.drawBitmap(reflectionImage, 0, height + reflectionGap,
                    null);

            // Create a shader that is a linear gradient that covers the
            // reflection
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    LinearGradient shader = new LinearGradient(0,originalImage.getHeight(), 0,bitmapWithReflection.getHeight() + reflectionGap,
                    0x70ffffff, 0x00ffffff, TileMode.CLAMP);
            // Set the paint to use this shader (linear gradient)
            paint.setShader(shader);
            // Set the Transfer mode to be porter duff and destination in
            paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.DST_IN));
            // Draw a rectangle using the paint with our linear gradient
            canvas.drawRect(0, height, width,
            bitmapWithReflection.getHeight() + reflectionGap, paint);

            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmapWithReflection);
        android.widget.Gallery.LayoutParams imgLayout = new CoverFlow.LayoutParams( 200, 200);

            imageView.setLayoutParams(imgLayout);
            imageView.setPadding(50, 100, 50, 20);
            imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
            mImages[index++] = imageView;

        }
        return true;
```

Comment: in the above link code this method not working createReflectedImages()

Answer (score 0):

You can use [This Coverflow](https://code.google.com/p/android-coverflow/) in your project. It gives you option to add reflection in coverflow. I have used this in one of my previous apps

Edited -

Blog you have mentioned is using adapter which is extending BaseAdapter and is using **createReflectedImages()** method only

If you look into source code of [link](https://code.google.com/p/android-coverflow/) I have provided, there is **CoverFlowTestingActivity** is there which is using following code to setup coverflow

```
private void setupCoverFlow(final CoverFlow mCoverFlow, final boolean reflect) {
    BaseAdapter coverImageAdapter;
    if (reflect) {
        coverImageAdapter = new ReflectingImageAdapter(new ResourceImageAdapter(this));
    } else {
        coverImageAdapter = new ResourceImageAdapter(this);
    }
    mCoverFlow.setAdapter(coverImageAdapter);
    mCoverFlow.setSelection(2, true);
    setupListeners(mCoverFlow);
}
```

Here you can see that if we want to reflection of images **ReflectingImageAdapter** in conjuction with **ResourceImageAdapter** which is extending **AbstractCoverFlowImageAdapter**.

I think this is the game changer for you

Comment: @silver, Thanq for  your quick responce hey both are same

Comment: hi same  method i'm using what you specify but not getting reflection, why?